# How to add class to nav bar if scroll is on top with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scroll, uinavigationbar

I want to add a class named "is-attached" to the navigation bar if the scroll is on the top of the page.

It's something quite easy to do with jQuery, but I'm trying to do it with vanilla js, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for scrollTop property to see if page is scrolled or not, and if not add the class. try this document.body.scrollTop

Comment: neat..and how do I run a function when scrolling?